# Import of NAS-data, (norm-based data exchange interface)

Tags: qgis, import

Is there any possibility to import nas-data in QGIS. NAS (norm-based data exchange interface) is a XML-based format. German cadastral-data is only available in this format.

Comment: Could you link to a sample file?

Comment: Any luck with it? It is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The GDAL build from [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141013002306/http://www.gisinternals.com:80/sdk/) offers reading of "NAS" format, the standalone QGIS Dufour 32bit for Windows as well.

I have no problem moving the test data given below into Dufour.

You can test your installation by typing `ogrinfo --formats` in the OSGEO4W shell
The output is not sorted alphabetically.

If NAS is included, you can transform the data with ogr2ogr to another format that QGIS can understand, or `Add Vector layer` to load it into QGIS directly.

See also:

http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_nas.html

http://trac.wheregroup.com/PostNAS

Test data:

http://www.lgn.niedersachsen.de/portal/live.php?navigation_id=11043&article_id=51644&_psmand=35