# QGIS, NAS and "Xerces XML parsing library"

Tags: qgis

Since the beginning of this year 2017 the standard geo information and data of Northrhine Westphalia are available for free: https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/

Including also data from the land registry (land parcels, etc):
https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/lika/alkis_sek/bda_oe/

I have downloaded and unzipped the data for Solingen and Aachen:
bda_oe_05122000_Solingen_EPSG25832_NAS.zip
bda_oe_05334000_Städteregion_Aachen_EPSG25832_NAS.zip

I use qgis 2.14 - I can select and see the XML-files when I select NAS as data type, which I want to open as vector layer..

But I do not see any content. The attribute table seems to be empty.

I have found out that it needs the "Xerces XML parsing library". But I do not know if it is part of QGIS 2.14?

The is a similar discussion:

[Import of NAS-data, (norm-based data exchange interface)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84310/import-of-nas-data-norm-based-data-exchange-interface)

How can I find out if the "Xerces XML parsing library" is installed and if not - how can I install it?

Comment: Does it work to just drag and drop the xml file to your project from the browser? It should open the xml and show you the layers and objectcount. There you can select and open the layers. The xml parser is installed alongsinde Qgis. Nothing more needed.